# Separate seizing operations after split

Tags: split, anylogic

I am modelling a production system. The problem appears while doing to separate seizing after a split. Here an image of the production flow:

[Process Flow Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuLW5.png)

1. Agent 1 enters the Split. No seizing has been done yet.
2. A copy of the Agent 1 is being created. We'll call it Agent 2.
3. Agent 1 gets seized to a resource out of the resource pool.
4. Agent 2 gets seized to a different resource out of a different resource pool.
5. Both Agents are being processed.
6. Both agents get combined and should continue as Agent 1 (If necessary, a new Agent could be created as well)

The problem appears at step number 6. This is the message as soon as the simulation crashes:

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PubBb.png)

> Exception during discrete event execution:
>   root.combine:
>   Agent being disposed possesses 1 unreleased resource units
>   Pool(s): root.Printer_Pool...

If I position "Seize_Printer" block after the combine, but keep the Seize_Batch_into_BU, the model works fine. I strongly suppose, that the the problems lies in the combine block at that it uses the Agent 1 to unite the two spited duplicates and can  not process both sized Resources of the two Resource pools.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine agents that are seized by a resource... that's a rule. You need to release the resources you seized with the seize blocks before the combine block...